# 404 for products in subcategories in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new in WooCommerce, and the last week i'm trying to solve problem with permalinks for WooCommerce in WP.
My client want a certain structure for products URL's:
`site.com/category/product` or `site.com/category/subcategory/product`
In WP Permalinks settings I definite that structure:
Products Custom: `/%product_cat%/%product%`
 In this case everything works fine except one thing, the URL of product page become:
`site.com/category/product/product` or `site.com/category/subcategory/product/product/product`
But if I setup this structure: `/%product_cat%` I just receive 404 on every product.
Sorry for my english, please help with that problem.

Comment: this link may help http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? If you did, please write an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Did you [flush your permalinks](https://typerocket.com/flushing-permalinks-in-wordpress/) after changing the settings?

There shouldn't be any need to include `%product%`in the Product permalinks setting.

Simply use Custom: `/%product_cat%` and it should work.